# Font awesome CSS Does Not Work in Symfony

Tags: php, html, css, symfony, font-awesome

I include font awesome CSS in Symfony twig file.

```
{% stylesheets
"@AppBundle/public/admin/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
"@AppBundle/public/admin/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.css"
"@AppBundle/public/admin/dist/css/sb-admin-2.css"
"@AppBundle/public/admin/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css"
%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% endstylesheets %}
```

It applies in this page. I check this, but icon class is not applied with the font. Please give me solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I suggest reading the following page....

http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

You'll need to supply code that can be used to replicate the issue.

Comment: live font awesome link properly work in my site but i can download in my local folder it not working

Comment: I have font awesome worked without live links. All you need is 1) `app/console assets:install --symlink`, then 2) `app/console assetic:dump --env=prod`

Comment: and if you still have error after doing actions from my previous comment, please, let me know, but add your errors to your question/comment.

Comment: sorry frdf bt it command not work in my cmd `app/console assets:install --symlink` i also try this `php app/console assets:install --symlink` but it not work

Comment: @jay when you write comment for somebody, please, add @ + nickname(will autocompleted after typing first characters). Then I will be notified. What's mean "not work" ? do you call this command from the root of your project? What kind of errors do you get?